# Dynamic Pagination in Django Templates

Tags: django, html, css, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to achieve a style in css3 with dynamic pagination suing Django as backend. I don't know how to make it happen as I am not able to make it work with while adding form to get user preference. Also having hard time to work with css3 to exactly rebuild the form removing button group option to get pagination.

Following is what I need to achieve:
[image]

Views.py:

```
class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = Product
    paginate_by = 12

    def get_paginate_by(self, queryset):
        return self.request.GET.get('paginate_by', self.paginate_by)
```

Original Template HTML5 code:

```
<div class="filter-show btn-group">
    <label data-translate="collections.toolbar.show">Show</label>
    <button class="btn btn-2 dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <i class="icon-exchange"></i>

      <span>12</span>

      <i class="icon-chevron-down"></i>
    </button>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">


      <li  class="active" ><a href="12">12</a></li>
      <li ><a href="16">16</a></li>
      <li ><a href="32">32</a></li>
      <li ><a href="all" data-translate="collections.toolbar.all">All</a></li>         
    </ul>
  </div>
```

What I am trying to do is:

```
<div class="filter-show btn-group">

            <label>Show</label>
            <button class="btn btn-2 dropdown-toggle" >

              <i class="icon-exchange"></i>

              <span>12</span>

              <i class="icon-chevron-down"></i>
            </button>
            <form action="" method="get">
            <select class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" name="paginate_by">
              <option class="active" ><a href="12">12</a></option>
              <option><a href="16">16</a></option>
              <option><a href="32">32</a></option>
              <option><a href="all" data-translate="collections.toolbar.all">All</a></option>

            </select>
                </form>
          </div>
```

Related css code is following:

```
<style>
                .toolbar .btn-group.filter-show { margin-left: 10px; }

                .toolbar button.dropdown-toggle {
                float: none;
                border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
                color: #505050;
                background: #fff;
                line-height: 34px;
                padding: 0 50px 0 10px;
                position: relative;
                text-transform: capitalize;
                width: 170px;
                text-overflow: ellipsis;
                white-space: nowrap;
                overflow: hidden;
                }
                .toolbar .filter-show button.dropdown-toggle {
                width: 120px;
                }
                .btn-group>.btn:last-child:not(:first-child), .btn-group>.dropdown-toggle:not(:first-child) {
                border-top-left-radius: 0;
                border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
                }
                </style>
```

There are two type of views on HTML5 side. First button is Grid and Second button is List from left. So if user selects Grid then all the columns in "show" area will be changed to grid of 12, 16, 32 and all. If selected List then accordingly list of 12, 16, 32 and all. 
Let me know about solution.

Answer (score 0):

Its all event based, lets say you a default view as grid view and number of items to be displayed is 12, so when you change either of the two parameter shoot out a ajax request and get template rendered as per the new parameters and replace the existing part of page where you are showing items with new template.

For eg.

```
<div class=items"></div>
```

is where all the items are listed, so on change of every parameter you can just replace contents of items div with the a template rendered as per new parameters for pagination.

Feel free to ask questions, in case I might have misunderstood your problem or I am being unclear.

**Edit:**

In your Django views, I assume you know how to pagination module, there you can mention the number of products you want to see in a single page. So, for example lets say you need 16 products per page, so you use paginator accordingly. Following this you can simple use template based on user's selection and pass the list of products from you view to that template.

For reference, [Django pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/pagination/)

Comment: Though I don't understand the solution....but let me give you the way I am trying to handle it. I need to set two jquery selectors one on grid view and one for list. Grid will be active by default as user sees the list. These two templates in theory should have code for grid with looping the list for products and grid for products. Further I need to include the templates for 12 with paginate_by=12, 16, 32 or all for both lists and grids. I've tried to implement it but when I set templates with include parameters it starts showing all template(s) data repeatedly.

Comment: @ShaziaNusrat I have updated the answer look in edit section, I have mentioned about django pagination. See, as far as your UI is concerned there are only two parameters type of listing(grid, list) and number of products on page. You can use pagination module to fix number of products and type of listing is just an indication as to which template you would use.

Comment: I proposed same solution more or less and I actually tried it before posting the question. It would be better if you implement it before you suggest. :-)

Comment: Well, i have done quiet a few implementation a such! :D If you tried it why couldn't you make it happen? Where did you get stuck?